# Need to select very specific element using querySelector without returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer, web-inspector

I'm scraping a site for data using Puppeteer and need to get a really specific piece of data from the site, I'm trying to use querySelector to get the classname of where the data is but its proven rather difficult because there are 22 other elements that use the exact classname(the classname is FormData), out of the 22 its the 18th and I've been trying to select it and print it out but to no avail, I always get the same error or something along the lines.

**Code**

```
// MODULES
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

// Url where we get and scrape the data from
const URL = "https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/category=form-cat2";

(async () => {
    try {
        const chromeBrowser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
        const page = await chromeBrowser.newPage();
        await page.goto(URL, {timeout: 0});

    const getInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const secTableEN = document.querySelector(".table td.entity-name");
        const secTableFiled = document.querySelector(".table td.filed");
        const secTableLinkPrice = document.querySelector('.FormData')[17];

        return {
            secTableEN: secTableEN.innerText,
            secTableFiled: secTableFiled.innerText,
            secTableLinkPrice: secTableLinkPrice.innerText,
        };
    });

    console.log(
        "Name: " + getInfo.secTableEN, '\n' +
        "Amount Purchased: " + getInfo.secTableLinkPrice, '\n'
    );

    await page.close();
    await chromeBrowser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})();
```

The error I'm always getting is:`Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')` and only always happens when I try returning the `secTableLinkPrice.innerText` the other two alone always work fine. What can I do?

Comment: `.FormData:nth-child(46)` or `document.querySelectorAll('.FormData')[46]`

Comment: Please update the question to include the name of the class that returns 70 items.  What element is "secTableLinkPrice" supposed to reference on the page?  You also have document.querySelector('.FormData')[46] in your code, but that returns an undefined as there is no .FormData class used anywhere on the page. Plus it should be querySelectorAll  if you want a node list.

Comment: The name of the class is `.FormData` and it returns 22, not 70 instances, sorry. Well if you check the website and use the inspector you'll find 22 different instances of FormData. Go to the site, click any link under 'Form and Files' and in the popup, the Common Stock price is the exact element I need, its HTML is a `<span class="FormData">a number inside here</span>`. And @KonradLinkowski using `document.querySelectorAll('.FormData:nth-child')[46];` I don't get the error anymore but what the console logs is 'undefined'.

Comment: What data are you trying to get? Are you _sure_ you can rely on it being the 18th? What's up with the 46th, then? There's usually a better identifier than that.

Comment: The price from the popup
[link](https://ibb.co/MGWR3PZ)

Comment: I'm confused. The screenshot looks nothing like your URL https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/category=form-cat2 which has no elements matching `.FormData`. What popup are you referring to?

Comment: When you click on one of the '4(insider trading report)' links to the left of every row a popup with those details comes up

Comment: OK, thanks. Your code doesn't do that, so it probably should for starters, I'd think. Which row do you want the price for? Intercepting the XML response is probably the easiest way to get this data, for example https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1793855/000195295222000008/xslF345X03/primary_doc.xml.

Comment: The very first row, the list on the site updates multiple times in a day, its a live/dynamic list, so what I just need is the first latest row. How would I go by getting this XML response?

Comment: See my answer, but the thing is, there are different types of XML reports. Type 4 has a price, others don't (type 3 and 3/A at a glance). So it's unclear how to handle the cases that don't have prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the price you want from the top result is in a popup, so you need to click on one of the `.preview-file` links to make that popup appear. Only then can you select `.FormData` from the iframe modal.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

const url = "<YOUR URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const $ = (...args) => page.waitForSelector(...args);
  await (await $(".filetype .preview-file")).click();
  const frame = await (await $("#ipreviewer")).contentFrame();
  await frame.waitForSelector(".FormText");
  const price = await frame.$$eval(".FormText", els =>
    els.find(e => e.textContent.trim() === "$")
      .parentNode
      .textContent
      .trim()
  );
  console.log(price);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Now, the popup triggers a network request to an XML file (which appears to be HTML), so it might be easiest to just download that, since it probably has all of the data you want. In the code below, I'm actually parsing and traversing that HTML with Puppeteer, so it looks like more work, but perhaps you could just save this file to disk, depending on your needs:

```js
// ... same as above ...

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const responseP = page.waitForResponse(res =>
    res.status() === 200 && res.url().endsWith(".xml")
  );
  const a = await page.waitForSelector(".filetype .preview-file");
  await a.click();
  const html = await (await responseP).text();
  await page.evaluate(html => document.body.outerHTML = html, html);
  const price = await page.$$eval(".FormText", els =>
    els.find(e => e.textContent.trim() === "$")
      .parentNode
      .textContent
      .trim()
  );
  console.log(price);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Finally, some documents don't have a price, so the above code only works on the "4 (Insider trading report)". Furthermore, I haven't validated that *all* of these "type 4" reports are exactly the same. You'll probably want to handle this in your code and proceed carefully.

Comment: Would there be a way to make it exclude anything that isn't "4(Insider trading)"?

Comment: Sure. `if (await a.evaluate(el => el.textContent.contains("4(Insider trading)")) { /* do it */ }` should work.

Comment: Alright, it works. Apparently the correct syntax is `.includes()` not `.contains`

Comment: `.contains()` worked in my current Chrome but that's probably better.